# What is the url expected on the open id client.callback method? How do I get the tokens?

Tags: node.js, openid-connect, openid

I'm trying to implement this flow: https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client#authorization-code-flow

I've done the previous steps, but I don't understand what is the URL expected in the `client.callback` method:

```js
const tokenSet = await client.callback('https://client.example.com/callback', params, { code_verifier });
```

The documentation for the method is also not explicit enough for my knowledge. https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/blob/main/docs/README.md#clientcallbackredirecturi-parameters-checks-extras

I looked into the URLs returned by the issuer but non of them stand out to me as necessary for a callback, but since this client.callback seems to be returning the tokens I imagine it's calling the `token_endpoint` at some point, or is the url supposed to be the token endpoint? If so, why is it not fetched in a similar way as the authorizationUrl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed the redirect URL in which the auth code was received, and 'callback' seems to be calling the token endpoint directly.

It hadn't worked when I tried because I had another issue with the callback parameters, but turns out I can send them as `{code: auth_code}` and that's it. I was trying to create the params with `client.callbackParams` like in the example, but my request was a WebApi fetch request and not one accepted by TS when trying to follow the example `const params = client.callbackParams(req);`. `callbackParams` does accept a string so I sent the code rather than the request, but it was not generating valid params from it.